# AngularJS, why there is a different behaviour while changing these two boolean properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular version: 1.6.0

I have a problem in understanding why I notice different behaviours in notifing to the view a change in a boolean property.

This is the view:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController as viewModel">

      <h1>
      "IsLoading" value: {{ viewModel.isLoading }}
      </h1>

      <h1>
      "IsLoadingV2" value: {{ viewModel.isLoadingV2 }}
      </h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
(function() {

angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller("testController", testController);

function testController($interval) {

  viewModel = this;
  viewModel.isLoading = true;
  viewModel.isLoadingV2 = true;

  viewModel.refreshView = function () {

      viewModel.isLoading = !viewModel.isLoading;
      viewModel.DoNothing();
      viewModel.isLoading = !!viewModel.isLoading;

      viewModel.isLoadingV2 = true;
      viewModel.DoNothing();
      viewModel.isLoadingV2 = false;

  };

  viewModel.DoNothing = function() {
      // 
  }


   var invertPropertyTimer = $interval(function () {

     viewModel.refreshView();

   }.bind(this), 1000);


}

})();
```

If you run the code above, you will notice that:

- `viewModel.isLoading = !viewModel.isLoading;` updates correctly the property, and correctly reflects its change to the view
- Setting directly `true` and `false` doesn't work.

What's the reason?

You can find the full working example on Plunker (last version): https://plnkr.co/edit/HiOQDVBQ7Wztmj5Dr8zb?p=preview

Comment: See your JS console :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interval that is called every second is executing the whole refreshView() function every second.

So you start off with isLoading, isLoadingV2 = true.

The first time the function is called:

```
isLoading = !isLoading // isLoading = false
DoNothing()
isLoading = !isLoading // isLoading = true

isLoadingV2 = true // isLoadingV2 = true
DoNothing()
isLoadingV2 = false; // isLoadingV2 = false
```

So isLoading at the end of the first refreshView function call is true and isLoadingV2 at the end of the first refreshView function call is false (which is reflected in your view).

Second time refreshView is called (1 second after the first time refreshView was called):

```
isLoading = !isLoading // isLoading goes from true -> false
DoNothing()
isLoading = !isLoading // isLoading goes from false -> true

viewModel.isLoadingV2 = true //isLoadingV2 = true
DoNothing()
isLoadingV2 = false; //isLoadingV2 = false
```

And so on.. so you see each time the refreshView is called, isLoading has changed by the end of the function call where as isLoadingV2 is always false at the end of the call so the view.

Comment: Understood! Is the view notified only at the end of the function call?

Comment: So, the new question is: how can I achieve the property change of the View inside a function?

Comment: @FrancescoB. To answer your first question, I think it's not that the view is only notified at the end of the function call but rather that you set isLoadingV2 to false right after setting it to true. If you add a delay between it, you would probably see the view update. As for your second question, what are you trying to achieve? It seems you could use the first method of changing the iLoading variable to the opposite of what it is.

Comment: I tried to set a timeout, but it doesn't work either. I wanted to achieve to have a loading screen to be shown while performing a long time operation.

Comment: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9EjxOIpzdWh0oCzepVI8) If you run this, you'll see the update on both variables upon the first run.

Comment: Yes, but the first "block" of code, where there is viewModel.isLoading is always changing, so the problem isn't that DoNothing() is too fast because It does nothing. Do you agree?